# How do I hover over span to let a div appear?

Tags: html, css, popover

```
 #hello{
   font-size: 4em;
 }
 div.about{
   display: none;
 }
 #hello:hover  div.about {
   display: block;
 }



<pre id="hometext"><span id="hello">Hello!</span></pre>
<div class="about" id="about"><p>hello</p></div>
```

First of all, I am new to stackoverflow. Secondly, I want to over a specific part of a paragraph, the span, and then let this div appear. But it doesnt seem to work..

Comment: There’s no `#Naam` element. There’s no `#hallo` element, but a `#hello` element. Typo questions are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Xufox Sorry it was originally in dutch, so I changed it for visibilty. So the typo's weren't the problem

Comment: Hm, alright. The space between `#hello:hover` and `div.about` means that `div.about` should be an element _inside_ `#hello:hover`, which it isn’t. You could try `#hometext:hover + div.about` instead of `#hello:hover div.about`.

Comment: That partially works! But since within the paragraph there are more words in the goaltext, I want it only to appear if it goes over the span? Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to use javascript:

```
#hometext:hover + #about { display:none; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to specifically to that for the span and not for the complete paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this is what you asked for, but you can utilize the span element's onmouseover and onmouseout attributes.

With a little bit of javascript, you can achieve what I think you want to do:

```js
function hideDiv() {
  document.getElementById("divToHide").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById("divToHide").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
#divToHide {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#hoverMe {
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<div id="divToHide">
</div>

<br />

<p>
  This is a paragraph. If you hover <span id="hoverMe" onmouseover="hideDiv()" onmouseout="showDiv()">here</span>, it will hide the red box.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some javascript there:

```js
function showOtherDiv() {
 document.getElementById("about").style.display = "block";
}

function hideOtherDiv() {
 document.getElementById("about").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#hello {
    font-size: 4em;
}

div.about {
    display: none;
}

#hello:hover div.about {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<pre id="hometext">
    <span id="hello" onmouseover="showOtherDiv()" onmouseout="hideOtherDiv()">Hello!</span>
</pre>


<div class="about" id="about">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXNWPw)